# Can I reset variable declared in core.js file using CEWP?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

Can I declare variable in **Core.Js** file and assign value on any SharePoint page. Like putting CEWP on page and setting variable(residing in Core.js file) value dynamially?

I tried putting one variable in Core.js file, and in CEWP I reset value to x, but I am not getting x value in any function inside Core.js file. Let me know if this could happen, if yes than how?

Thanks,

Ashish Chotalia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that if you modify core.js, you are in an unsupported state, so i cannot recommend you do that.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/04/02/customization-of-core-js-file-in-sharepoint.aspx

Could you explain what you are trying to do and there is probably a better way.

**UPDATE**

Do you know that `AddDocLibMenuItems` already has a hook in it, to allow it to be overridden

```
function AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx)
{
    if (typeof(Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems) !="undefined")
    {
        if (Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx))
            return;
    }
```

If you defined a function `Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems`, you should be able to work without customising core.js

Comment: That's right, changing core.js file will affect whole sites on farm, I was thinking to declare global variable(like boolean) in core.js file, set value=0 default. On CEWP I will set it to 1 and than I can put condition for each function in core.js.

Comment: a condition to do what? change the functionality?

Comment: yes, We have AddDocLibMenuItems function defined in core.js file, I want to put condition based on that variable to render only certain menu.

Comment: I just want to disable certain functionality, like hide ViewPermission link in ECB menu on particular page.

Comment: Thanks, for comments. Finally I just modified core.js file and put condition to check whether page url contains "XXXX" string. If yes, than only hide other options like "Delete", Else it will work as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Customize or Override core.js file functions in Sharepoint](http://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/customize-or-override-core-js-file-functions-in-sharepoint/) @ [YoursAndMyIdeas](http://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com)